# Inserting dynamic data from variable to SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, gps

It's my first question in Stackoverflow so I want to say Hello everyone ;)
I have a problem. I'm trying to insert into SQLite database, data from variable.
In android, when you create a database, you do it in class OnCreate, so you can only put
static data, so what if I want to put here GPS data from variable (longitude or latitude) ?
I want to create big database, inserting position from GPS with 1s frequency.
Greetings

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(Database.DB_NAME,
MODE_PRIVATE, null);        db.execSQL(Database.DB_CREATE);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO baza(id,LEFT_POSITION, RIGHT_POSITION, GPS,
TIME) values (" + "1" + "," + x + "," + y + "," + z + "," + c +");");
    db.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Android Docs: Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

> The recommended method to create a new SQLite database is to create a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper and override the onCreate() method, in which you can execute a SQLite command to create tables in the database.

...

> You can then get an instance of your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation using the constructor you've defined. To write to and read from the database, call getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase(), respectively. These both return a SQLiteDatabase object that represents the database and provides methods for SQLite operations.